# stacking/margin issues only on far right of page with 3 divs [left=static][center=fluid][right=static]

Tags: css, fluid-layout

http://jsfiddle.net/JPt3X/2/

html-

```
<div class="page">
<div class="header boxshadowsmaller">
</div>

        <div class="mainleft boxshadowsmaller">
        </div>

        <div class="maincenter">
            <div id="videowrapper">
                <div class="videobox">
                    <object class="boxshadowsmaller" width="360" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=athenelive"><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=athenelive&auto_play=false" /></object>
                </div>
                <div class="videobox">
                    <object class="boxshadowsmaller" width="360" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=athenelive"><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=athenelive&auto_play=false" /></object>
                </div>
                <div class="videobox">
                    <object class="boxshadowsmaller" width="360" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=athenelive"><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=athenelive&auto_play=false" /></object>
                </div>
                <div class="videobox">
                    <object class="boxshadowsmaller" width="360" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=athenelive"><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=athenelive&auto_play=false" /></object>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainright boxshadowsmaller">
        </div>
    </div>
```

the css-

```
        html
        {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color:white;
            font: 12px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        }

        /* GENERIC */

        .clear
        {
            clear: both;
        }

        .border
        {
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 6px solid rgba(255, 204, 0, 0);
        }

        .boxshadowsmaller
        {
            box-shadow: 2px 3px 20px -3px #000000;
        }

        /* STRUCTURE */

        .header
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 120px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 10px 15px 15px 15px;
            background-color: orange;
        }

        .mainleft
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 290px;
            height: 100%;
            left: 15px;
            background-color: blue;
            z-index: 3;
        }

        .maincenter
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 1290px;
            min-width: 390px;
            left: 315px;
            right: 315px;
            z-index: 2;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .mainright
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 290px;
            height: 100%;
            right: 15px;
            background-color: red;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        #videowrapper
        {
            max-width: 1290px;
            min-width: 360px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .videobox
        {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        }

        .page
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
```

---

The left and center divs are ok being anchored to the left side of the page with absolute and margin. But the right div is giving me trouble. I'm not sure how to make it properly 'stack' when you shrink the horizontal size of the browser. It goes behind the center and left divs. It should stack and then get pushed off the side of the window just like the left and center ones do.

Also, I'm not sure why the header margin-right isn't being applied?

And I realize the vertical overflow yuckiness. I just want the stacking to work properly first. :]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
.maincenter { width: 100%; }
```

could help?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the header right side margin with

```
.header{ width: auto; }
```

And solved the stacking / overflow by changing

```
#page{ min-width: VALUE;)
```

where VALUE = is the sum of my margins and minimum widths across the layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/JPt3X/4/